# How can i set a limit to send memes (discord.js bot)

Tags: discord.js

When i use my meme command i get like 100 memes instead of one, how can i make generate only  1 meme ?
Here is my code:

```
        const { MessageEmbed } = require ("discord.js");
        const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

           module.exports = {
               name: "meme",
               category: "fun",
               description: "Sends an epic meme",
           }

           bot.on("message", async message => {
               const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme"];
                const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

               const img = await randomPuppy();

               const embed = new MessageEmbed()
               .setColor("RANDOM")
               .setImage(img)
               .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
               .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

               message.channel.send(embed)

           })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed my issue: i add

`if (message.content == "meme"){}`

above `const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme"];`

and it seems working